# Utf8 problem with IE and GET request using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, encoding, utf-8

Using javascript, I'm setting the src of an iframe to an URL passing a GET variable, urlencoded with unescape( encodeURIComponent( message ) ).

With IE, this works the *first* time I load the iframe.The utf-8 characters, as the var_dump($_GET) reveals server-side, are okay.  But next calls, all I get is garbage.

On the other hand, if I just send in the message variable, without any escaping, the first time I set the iframe, the var_dump($_GET) shows the characters are wrong.  But next calls, the variable is correctly set!!

Any idea of whats going on?

Comment: What do you mean by 'calling' an iframe? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Ok, i mean, setting the url to an iframe. The first time i set the iframe url (with a query string with utf8 characters), i get one result in the server-side php script (garbage if not encoded, ok if encoded). From that point, i get the opposite result (garbage if encoded, ok if not encoded).

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1. [Use these JS functions](http://farhadi.ir/downloads/utf8.js) for encoding / decoding your string to / from UTF8.
2. Save your code files with `UTF8 without BOM` encoding using any advanced text-editor / IDE like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Comment: At times like these, I wish that encoding scheme was called WTF-8 or WTF-I-8-This :p. (+1)

Comment: All the js and php is saved as UTF-8 without BOM.Using that js, i got the same result.The first time i use it to generate the query string, it works.The next times, it doesnt.
Btw..It just happens in IE..Firefox works like a charm.

Comment: Ok, i've noticed that it doesnt matter if the first request includes utf-8 or not.So, making a first a "fake" request to the same url *with no query string at all* , makes the real request correctly send the utf-8 encoded characters...Dirty hack